# Odd bug in SQL TRIM() function

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, select, trim

I have the following table:

```
select * from top3art;

            path             | count
-----------------------------+--------
 /article/candidate-is-jerk  | 338647
 /article/bears-love-berries | 253801
 /article/bad-things-gone    | 170098
```

I want to trim off '/article/' in path values, so I do this:

```
select *, trim(leading '/article/' from path) from top3art;

            path             | count  |       ltrim
-----------------------------+--------+--------------------
 /article/candidate-is-jerk  | 338647 | ndidate-is-jerk
 /article/bears-love-berries | 253801 | bears-love-berries
 /article/bad-things-gone    | 170098 | bad-things-gone
```

Rows 2 and 3 work just fine. But what happened to the 1st row??
It trimmed '/article/ca'. Why did it take 2 more characters?

Now watch what happens when I just trim '/articl':

```
select *, trim(leading '/articl' from path) as test from top3art;

            path             | count  |         test
-----------------------------+--------+----------------------
 /article/candidate-is-jerk  | 338647 | e/candidate-is-jerk
 /article/bears-love-berries | 253801 | e/bears-love-berries
 /article/bad-things-gone    | 170098 | e/bad-things-gone
```

That works as expected... Now watch what happens when I add one more char in my trim clause, '/article':

```
select *, trim(leading '/article' from path) as test from top3art;

            path             | count  |        test
-----------------------------+--------+--------------------
/article/candidate-is-jerk  | 338647 | ndidate-is-jerk
/article/bears-love-berries | 253801 | bears-love-berries
/article/bad-things-gone    | 170098 | bad-things-gone
```

Same as the first result! 
I can't make sense of this. 
Why is this happening?
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

`trim` removes any character in the first argument from the second argument, so it also removes the `c` and the `a` of "candidate". Instead of `trim`, you could use a `split_part` call:

```
select *, split_part(path, '/article/', 2) as test from top3art;
```

Comment: Thank you that also worked. However as I mentioned below, if trim() removes all the characters in the first arg, then why did it only remove the first 'ca' after '/article/'? Why didn't it remove the rest of the characters in the rest of the chars in '/article/'? i.e. 'i' or 'r'.

Comment: @KarimShaloh `trim` removes the leading (in this case) characters present in the first string from the second string until it encounters a character that isn't in the first string. Here, it stops when it encounters `n`, that isn't in `/article/`.

Answer (score 3):

Trim removes all signs you mentioned not words/phrases.
Instead of trim use replace()

```
select *, replace(path, '/article/','') from top3art;
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. However, if trim() removes all the characters mentioned, then why did it only remove the first 'ca' after '/article/'? Why didn't it remove the rest of the characters in the mentioned string? i.e. 'i' or 'r'.

Comment: Because 'n' and 'b' are the first characters from the left that are not in the character list '/aceilrt'

Comment: Ah. I get it now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @KarimShaloh Btw, a `replace` in this case is fine as long those paths have only the `/article/` at the start.  If not, then I you could use [regexp_replace](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/regexp_replace/) with the regex pattern `^/article/` instead.

Comment: yeah, or substring. if they all begin with '/article/'